# Rails: User logging out creates error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm going through www.railstutorial.org/ and I'm getting stuck on logging a user out of the app.

When I log out, I get an error in my terminal saying:

```
1) Error:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout:
ActionController::RoutingError: uninitialized constant UsessionsController
    test/integration/users_login_test.rb:29:in `block in <class:UsersLog
```

And this is my code for test/integration/users_login_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

    def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "login with invalid information" do
    get login_path
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    post login_path, session: { email: "", password: "" }
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    assert_not flash.empty?
    get root_path
    assert flash.empty?
  end

  test "login with valid information followed by logout" do
    get login_path
    post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' }
    assert is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
    delete logout_path
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    follow_redirect!
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path,      count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user), count: 0
  end
end
```

Any idea where I went wrong?

Comment: It looks like you may have a mispelling: `UsessionsController`.  Should that really be `SessionsController`?

Comment: I did! Thanks for the suggestion. it was in the routes.rb file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error, you might have an misspelling error: `UsessionsController` since you're testing login functionality, you probably wanted to define `SessionsController` in your controller definition.

Correcting the controller should solve the issue.